# How to put even numbers from matrix in separate vector in Julia?

Tags: matrix, vector, julia

I am solving some matrix problems in Julia and i need to put numbers that can be divided by 2 (or any other number) from matrix in separate vector. Generally, when I need to separate numbers from matrix that can be divided with 2 or 3 or 4...etc i can't index them properly. Basically, I need Julia equivalent for Matlab command:

```
vector=matrix(rem(matrix,2)==0)
```

.

I tried few things mentioned below:

```
vector=matrix[matrix.%2==0];

vector=(matrix.%2==0);
```

I expect output to be vector of numbers that can be divided with certain number but in first case I get errors and in second I only get "true" or "false".

This is my first post, so sorry if I made any mistakes or broke any rules.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to get what you want, that you almost got right, is the following:

```
julia> M = rand(1:10, 3,3)
3×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 3  10  7
 6   7  8
 2  10  6

julia> v = M[M .% 2 .== 0]
6-element Array{Int64,1}:
  6
  2
 10
 10
  8
  6
```

Note the extra dot in `.==` which applies the equality comparison elementwise.

A faster version would be to use [`findall`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/base/arrays/#Base.findall-Tuple%7BFunction,Any%7D):

```
julia> M[findall(x->x%2==0, M)]
6-element Array{Int64,1}:
  6
  2
 10
 10
  8
  6
```

Here, `x->x%2==0` is a anonymous function representing the find criterium. In the special case `x%2==0` this can simply be replaced by `iseven`:

```
julia> M[findall(iseven, M)]
6-element Array{Int64,1}:
  6
  2
 10
 10
  8
  6
```

You can also utilize [array-comprehensions](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/arrays/#man-comprehensions-1) to get what you want as well, which should be even faster:

```
julia> [x for x in M if iseven(x)]
6-element Array{Int64,1}:
  6
  2
 10
 10
  8
  6
```

Finally, perhaps the most idomatic option, is to use [`filter`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/base/collections/#Base.filter):

```
julia> filter(iseven, M)  
6-element Array{Int64,1}: 
  6                       
  2                       
 10                       
 10                       
  8                       
  6
```

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed answer! This solved my problem and I learned something new, too... I wish you all the best!

Comment: Glad my answer was helpful! Enjoy your next steps in Julia!

Comment: How would you make those even numbers that we found, change inside matrix to certain value(for example to 3)? So values at their positions are now equal to 3...

Comment: You could, for example, use `replace!(x->iseven(x) ? 3 : x, M)`.

Comment: I'd also add that if you've got some MATLAB code that seems like it should almost work except for the extra `.` dots you need to add, you can try the `@.` macro in front of it: this would have worked in your case to do `vector = @. matrix[matrix % 2 == 0]`

Comment: There is also filter, as in `filter(iseven, M)`, which, on my computer at least, is even faster, and possibly the most elegant. (Actually--scratch that. The comprehension is the fastest.)

Comment: @DNF Added a `filter` based version. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @DNF Thank you! That is great idea, too. It's amazing how many
different options exist for solving this problem...